# How do I access uploaded photos in in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have a form for creating a project, the project can contain five photos.

In my _form.html.erb I can't access my upladed photos when I'm calling `multipart => true` but in my show they are accessible. If there are any existing photos, I want to show the existing photos in the edit.erb and a delete option. I can access the uploaded photos in the show.

Here is my _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @project, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="newPaperclipFiles">

        <%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>

           <% if asset.object.new_record? %>
                 <%= asset.file_field :photo %>
           <% end %>

       <% end %>

</div>

<div class="existingPaperclipFiles">

     <% f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>

          <% unless asset.object.new_record? %>

                <div>
                        <%=image_tag asset.photo.url(:small) %>
                </div>
                        <%= asset.check_box :_destroy %>      
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The show.erb where I can access the photos:

```
    <div class="existingPaperclipFiles">

      <% @project.assets.each do |asset| %>
        <div>
        <%= image_tag asset.photo.url(:small) %>
      </div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @project.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @project.description %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

My asset model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'paperclip'

  belongs_to :project, :foreign_key => "project_id"
  attr_accessible :project_id, :photo
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {  :thumb => "600x600#", :medium => "300x300#", :small => "160x160#"}
end
```

My project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_permalink :title
  default_scope :order => 'created_at desc'
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :assets_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_uniqueness_of :title
  validates_presence_of :title
  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

---

EDIT:

Project contoller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:show]
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new()
    (5 - @project.assets.length).times { @project.assets.build }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
    end


  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
      @project = Project.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
      @assets = Project.includes(:assets).find_by_permalink(params[:id])
(5 - @project.assets.length).times { @project.assets.build }
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.create(params[:project])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    @project = Project.find_by_permalink(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(params[:project])
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :assets_attributes)
    end

end
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: No tumbnail photo is shown in my form when i am editing my a project that already have one photo uploaded. It does not work. But I can view existing photos in show.html.erb.

Comment: What's your controller like? I believe it will be something to do with the @variable.build option which enables `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but we can only tell if you show the controller code :)

Comment: @RichPeck added the controller :)

Comment: @jdartland so it renders a broken image, or what is the actual problem?

Comment: what happens when you try to print out @project.assets in edit view?

Comment: The problem is that it does not render anything in my form, I can't display the photos. But when i print @project.assets.photo.url in edit view it works..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo, but try adding the `=` here:

```
<% f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
```